# How to read values in a particular column of a CSV file in Batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, csv

I am planning to write a batch script wherein I need to scan the values from a particular column of a CSV file one by one and store them in a variable for further processing.

Say, following is the CSV file:

```
A1, B1, C1, D1, E1
A2, B2, C2, D2, E2
A3, B3, C3, D3, E3
.., .., .., .., ..
```

I have to read D1, execute a command using it's value, read D2, execute a command, and so on.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why is your "Comma Separated Value" file ... not comma separated? Are they tab or space separated? Are there spaces in the values themselves?

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=, " %%a in (data.csv) do (
    echo run command here "%%a"
)
```

- This runs for each line in the file
- "delims=, " splits the line on commas *or space characters*
- tokens=4 selects column 4 after the split

Comment: They are comma separated only. I forgot to add commas. Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @MandarShinde ok, I've adjusted my answer - if there are no spaces or commas inside the values, this should work.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler I think you're mixing up your syntax a bit. ;)

Comment: @MattWilliamson oops! PowerShell is contaminating my batch files. Fixed, thank you.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler - No prob. I figured it was PS or JS. You still forgot the `DO` but I added it in for ya.

Comment: @MattWilliamson I should test more. Ta.

Comment: At what point of time will it stop reading those values? If there are say 500 values, will it stop automatically after reading 500th value or keep going on?

Comment: @MandarShinde I think it goes all the way to the end of the file.

Answer (score -1):

### Use this, It will solve your problem :

```
CSVReader reader = null;

try 
{
    reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(dir));
    String[] row;
    List<?> content = reader.readAll();

    for (Object object : content) 
    {
        row = (String[]) object;
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) 
        {
            // display CSV values
                System.out.println("Cell column index: " + i);
                System.out.println("Cell Value: " + row[i]);
                System.out.println("-------------");
        }
    }
}catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: So, what language is this?

Comment: could not get properly?

Comment: @MattWilliamson It's java